# Modelling lunar motion in Python

Tags: orbital-motion, computational-physics, simulations

I'm trying to solve the equations of motion of the Moon in the Moon-Sun-Earth system (equations 1139-1141 here:http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node130.html)

My initial conditions were $ \boldsymbol{r} = <a,0,0> $, where a is the Lunar semi-major axis.
The initial velocities were $\boldsymbol{\dot{r}} = \omega a <0, cos\phi, sin\phi>$, where $\omega$ is the Lunar angular velocity and $\phi$ is the inclination of the Lunar orbit from the ecliptic plane.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

## Data
# Moon orbit semi-major axis
a = 384.748e6 # m
# Moon angular velocity around the Earth (27 days)
#omega = 2.6934e-6 # s^-1
omega = 0.2327 # days^-1

# Earth orbit semi-major axis
a_dash = 149.6e9 # m
# Earth angular velocity around the Sun (365 days)
#omega_dash = 1.9923e-7 # s^-1
omega_dash = 0.0172 # days^-1

# Initial conditions
# at t = 0,
# [x, xdot, y, ydot, z, zdot] - same as the motion vector
# 0.0898844565 rad = 5.15 deg
vy = omega*a*np.cos(0.0898844565)
vz = omega*a*np.sin(0.0898844565)

init = [a, 0, 0, vy, 0, vz]


# Equations of motion

# Returns the derivatives of x,y,z (u,v,w) and u,v,w in a vector [xdot, udot, ydot, vdot, zdot, wdot]
# r - states
rdot = np.zeros(6)

def motion(t, r):
    x = r[0]
    u = r[1] # xdot or velocity in x direction

    y = r[2]
    v = r[3] # ydot

    z = r[4]
    w = r[5] # zdot

    # the derivatives with respect to time
    # [xdot, udot, ydot, vdot, zdot, wdot] = [u, udot, v, vdot, w, wdot]
    # xdot
    rdot[0] = u
    # udot =
    rdot[1] = 2*omega*v + (omega**2+omega_dash**2/2)*x - omega**2 * x *a**3/(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)**3) + 3/2*omega_dash**2*(x*np.cos(2*(omega-omega_dash)*t) - y*np.sin(2*(omega-omega_dash)*t) )
    # ydot
    rdot[2] = v
    # vdot
    rdot[3] = -2*omega*u + (omega**2+omega_dash**2/2)*y - omega**2 * y *a**3/(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)**3) - 3/2*omega_dash**2*( x*np.sin(2*(omega-omega_dash)*t) + y*np.cos(2*(omega-omega_dash)*t) )
    # zdot
    rdot[4] = w
    # wdot
    rdot[5] = -omega_dash**2*z - omega**2 * z *a**3/(np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)**3)

    return rdot

# Solve system of ODEs
t_start = 0.
t_end = 5000
t_step = 1
ode =  spi.ode(motion)

# BDF method suited to stiff systems of ODEs
ode.set_integrator('vode',nsteps=500,method='bdf', rtol=0.1)
ode.set_initial_value(init,t_start)

ts = []
soln = []

while ode.successful() and ode.t < t_end:

    ode.integrate(ode.t + t_step)
    ts.append(ode.t)
    soln.append(ode.y)

t = np.vstack(ts)
x_soln, vx_soln, y_soln, vy_soln , z_soln, vz_soln = np.vstack(soln).T
```

I left out the plotting. Anyways, I expect to see an elliptical orbit and to see precession of nodes and apsidal precession. However, my results basically give me a linearly rising sine wave in both x in y. If I set the relative tolerance of the integrator to say 1%, then I get a constant solution that exponentionally approaches a sine wave as the integration time approaches the end of the integration integral.

If I approximate the radius as being equal to a (the semi-major axis of the Lunar orbit), then I do get an elliptical solution (with an orbital velocity that is 2x that of the actual Moon), because one of the terms in the equations simplifies itself. However the resulting sine waves are also part of a larger sine wave with a period of about 50 years, which I cannot explain.

As far as precession of nodes I'm expecting a sine wave with a period of 27 days in the x and y directions that is multiplied by a rotation matrix with the precession period. Am I imagining this correctly? What about apsidal precession, I can't really picture what that would look like on a graph? I also fear it's hard to notice both effects because the eccentricity of the orbit is so small.

I'm looking for any ideas where I might have gone wrong because I'm kind of running out of them myself.

Comment: If you have a Python question, then you are in the wrong place here. Generally, we aren't going to debug your code for you, sorry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about debugging code.

Comment: Sorry, I'll suppose I'll try and ask on overflow? Anyways I wasn't expecting anyone to debug my code, but instead see if my ideas are correct about what results I should be getting. On top of that I don't trust my initial conditions either at this point. So the code is there just in case someone saw a bad mistake I made.

Comment: The [Computational Science site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com) is probably better than StackOverflow for scientific computing questions. That's not to say this question is on-topic there (or that it is definitely off-topic here -- only 2 votes to close so far), but I'd recommend going there rather than StackOverflow for questions about simulating physical systems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just to be clear: I haven't looked at your code, I'm not responding to that. I'm submitting in the answer section because I have a general comment.

The treatment by Richard Fitzpatrick that you link to is an exercise in how to go about obtaining an analytic solution for the case of the the Sun-Earth-Moon three body problem.

In the general case of three bodies with mutual interactions there is no exhaustive solution, but in some cases some well chosen approximations can make it feasible to do the computations with pen and paper. As we know: for centuries this is what astronomers did in order to do astronomy: you find ways to bring the calculations within reach of being handled with pen and paper.

These approaches are not used when electronic computers are used to calculate celestial motion. On an electronic computer you use Newton's law of gravity in its direct form:

$$ F = \frac{Gm_1 m_2}{r^2} $$

(Wich in the case of the Sun, Earth, Moon system of course means that you process three interactions: Sun-Earth, Sun-Moon, Earth-Moon.)

To my knowledge that is how on electronic computers all simulations of celestial motion are done.

My suggestion: use cartesian coordinates, and use a non-rotating coordinate system. If you also want to plot the motion with respect to some rotating coordinate system then you can apply that coordinate transformation to the result of the numerical integration.

(Again, I suppose that in past centuries in order to bring the calculations within reach of pen and paper it was in some circumstances efficient to express the equation of motion and the intended coordinate transformation in a combined formula, and proceed from there.)

---

Let me add some general considerations.

**Trade-offs**

With todays computing power: for the purpose of processing a three body case your computational power is effectively limitless. Only when you want to to model, say, an entire galaxy you need a supercomputer.

In the treatment by Fitzpatrick there are approximations, he mentions neglecting higher order terms. Those approximations introduce error. Negligable in the short run, but over time you get accumulation of error.

If the only expression you evaluate is Newton's law in bare form then there is *no approximation* in the formula's themselves. Then only one source of error remains, the precision level of the numerical integration. You have a trade-off there. Higher precision level may limit you to, say, computing only a couple of thousand years of Moon motion. Lower precision level may allow you to compute millions of years, but probably by that time accumulation of error has made the end state meaningless.

(Also, over time the distance between the Earth and the Moon is increasing. There are tidal effects that result in the Earth slowing down and the Moon being pulled to a higher orbit. So a long term model would have include that gravitational interaction.)

So it's good to be aware of the trade-offs that apply in your case, and to try and make sensible decisions.

One important trade-off, I think: the simpler the expressions that the numerical integration evaluates, the more debuggable the simulation is. Newton's law of gravity is a simple, transparent expression.

**Displaying the results**

Again, since your computing power is effectively limitless you can display the results of the computation in any way you want. For instance, you can choose to set up a side by side display of the motion with respect to some particular inertial coordinate system, and next to it the motion with respect to some particular rotating coordinate system. The required coordinate transformation for that is trivial.

That is, given your limitless computing power the decision on how to *display* the results is independent from the decision of how to execute the numerical integration itself.

There is no such thing as: "I want to visualize the results as motion with respect to this rotating coordinate system so I must do all the computation in that rotating coordinate system." Obviously the two are independent.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I just assumed that the problem would be easier to solve numerically if I simplified it analitically first.

Comment: There is no reason NOT to work in a rotating coordinate system that is approximately geocentric, if you want to. Just include the fictitious centrifugal and Coriolis forces correctly and everything will work. I spend most of my working life solving nonlinear dynamics problems numerically that way (and the models usually have a few hundred thousand degrees of freedom, not 4) It far easier to visualise the results in a rotating coordinate system than an inertial one, when (as in the OP's problem) the orbital motions of the earth wrt the sun and the moon wrt the earth don't have a common period.

Comment: I see. I figured it'd still all work out. I suppose I must fix my code somehow then.